# RHEL 7.5 Cannot Yum install from text file

Tags: bash, redhat, yum, rpm

I cannot figure out why installing packages listed in a text file with Yum wouldn't work but for some reason it does not. Yum cycles through all the listed package names and and lists them as available but at the end it shows the last package as installed with "Nothing to do". There has to be a way of doing this.  I tried the following:

```
yum -y install $(/tmp/installs.txt)
yum install -y $(awk '{printf("%s ",$1)}' /tmp/installs.txt)
for i in $( /tmp/installs.txt);do yum install $i -y;done
yum install `cat /tmp/installs.txt | tr '\n' ' '`
yum install $(cat /tmp/BSTNinstalls.txt)
```

Is this not allowed in Redhat or is there another way to go about this?

Comment: try these:
for i in `cat /tmp/installs.txt`;do yum install $i -y;done OR
yum install -y `awk '{printf("%s ",$1)}' /tmp/install.txt`
OR paste the whole output if you are still facing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yum -y install $(cat /tmp/installs.txt | xargs)
```

It's works for Me in my CentOS.